# Heroku deployment of a Node+React app is not working

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to deploy my React+Node application to Heroku. I'm using Git as well.
The CMD keeps running this code and never stops:

```
remote:        > npm run build
remote:        > reactexpress@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_cd43acb7
```

On the Heroku log it shows "Build in progress".
I followed the instructions step by step a few times.
My scripts:

```
    "client-install": "cd client && npm install",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "npm run build",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd public && npm i && npm run build",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
```

Answer (score 0):

From your scripts, your build command looks like:

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "build": "npm run build"
    }
}
```

As we can see your `build` command calls `build` command, which then calls `build` command and then... You see where is the issue?

So to sum up, you need to update the build command to actually do something (not just calls itself) or just remove it if you don't wish to build anything.